# ways to split a list of strings in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that has keys and values

e.g.

key: 'ROOF'

Value:'R UW1 F'

I've put the values in a list that matches one of the keys and in order to translate the value into IPA pronunciations.

EX:
'R UW1 F' translates to 'ruf'

but in order to convert the Vowel phonemes into IPA pronunciations I need to split the given value form the Dictionary.

So my question is how could you split ['R UW1 F'] into ['R', 'UW1', 'F']

Comment: Use the `split()` method on each value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_strings = ['R UW1 F']
list_of_split_strings = [s.split(' ') for s in list_of_strings]
```

Comment: gives me an empty list.

Comment: @user11505855 are you sure you ran the exact code?

Comment: I just retested it. print(list_of_split_strings) >>> [['R', 'UW1', 'F']]

Comment: yea it works I just forgot to print the output.

Comment: You can accept the answer so others will know the question has been answered,